# What is the cURL command request to generate an mp3 text-to-speech file?

Tags: text-to-speech

I am not a dev. I'm looking to generate synthetic voices for digital books which I am creating. I would really appreciate some help with the following. After inputting the curl command, what is the next step to generate a sound file? I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to proceed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate audio files from text on your own desktop, depending on which OS your are running:

MacOs: [MAC's "say" command to MP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501663/macs-say-command-to-mp3)

Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/178736/generate-mp3-file-from-espeak

Windows: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search?q=text+to+audio (warning: store downloads on your own risk)

If you have a server running, you may use the server to generate the audio:

php: [eSpeak to mp3 in php on both windows and linux (online text-to-speech)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584205/espeak-to-mp3-in-php-on-both-windows-and-linux-online-text-to-speech)

nodejs: [text to audio file on node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861592/text-to-audio-file-on-node-js)

python: [How can I convert text to speech (mp3 file) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516572/how-can-i-convert-text-to-speech-mp3-file-in-python)

Comment: Thank you very much. I greatly appreciate the help. Best of luck in all of your endeavors.